# Logback DBAppender url

Tags: sql, oracle, logback, ora-00904

I'm trying to use Logback's DBAppender. My logback.xml has the following appender:

```
</appender>
 <appender name="DatabaseAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
  <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
   <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClass>
   <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST_URL:PORT:SERVICE_NAME</url>
   <user>USER</user>
   <password>PASS</password>
 </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

the url given works with other java classes in the same project but it fails with logback giving the following error

```
ORA-00904: "ARG3": invalid identifier

        at java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "ARG3": invalid identifier
```

where ARG3 is the `<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST_URL:PORT:SERVICEID</url>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be interested in the Oracle statement resulting in this error.
My guess is that it is trying an INSERT INTO table (arg1, arg2, arg3) values (...);
when the table doesn't contain that column.

If you don't know what the table is then checking [here](http://blog.flimatech.com/?p=813) about forcing an error dump when the 904 error is encountered.

I can do a

```
ALTER system SET EVENTS '904 TRACE NAME ERRORSTACK LEVEL 3';
```

Then, when the error is raised, the database generates a trace file which should show the problem statement similar to the following :

```
ORA-00904: "FRFRF": invalid identifier
Current SQL statement for this session:
select frfrf from dual
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the advice. I dug a little and found out they changed the database structure but didn't update the documentation. From 0.9.19 onward the logging_event table needs the following four columns:
arg0 VARCHAR(254);
arg1 VARCHAR(254);
arg2 VARCHAR(254);
arg3 VARCHAR(254);

Answer (score 0):

FOR DATASOURCE CONNECTIONS:

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
      <dataSource
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>
        <jdbcUrl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</jdbcUrl>
        <user>system</user>
        <password>a</password>
      </dataSource>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
```

FOR DRIVERMANAGER CONNECTIONS:

```
 <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
      <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
      <url>jdbc:mysql://host_name:3306/datebase_name</url>
      <user>username</user>
      <password>password</password>
    </connectionSource>
  </appender>
```